# Making electrical muscle stimulating device

Tags: power-supply

I’m wondering if I should use a power transformer at 9 volts AC @200mA straight current.

Not pulsing or any on / off function.

Just on —-buzzzzz....... with 2 medical leads: 2 sticky pads made for these devices will be used stuck to my back or neck.

Is this dangerous? (9v ac/ 200mA)

This is attempting a homemade muscle stimulating device.

Comment: You have done no research and are asking a bunch of strangers for advice. This is not a good start. 30 mA is enough to kill. 9 V isn't enough to generate much current in the human body.

Comment: This is a recipe for injuring someone. First, you need to get a college degree in electronics to understand all of the intricacies of AC and DC. Then you need to specialize in medical-grade electronics, which are harder to build precisely because they can be dangerous. It is FAR easier to just buy a muscle stimulator.

Comment: Not a good project for a beginner. I wouldn't even recommend an EKG home project for a beginner. And an EKG is a passive fairly safe device. Anything that makes good contact with skin is a potentially risky device.

Comment: @Maple - I know they aren't the same, sorry, you missed my point.

Comment: @Mattman944 indeed, I did.

Comment: The only real question OP presented was _"Is this dangerous???"_. The only possible answer is YES, IT IS VERY DANGEROUS. If you had some clue about this you wouldn't be here asking for advice.

Comment: FYI these devices have been proven inefficient a while ago. Yes they might help to people with a total atrophy, but have really no positive effect on healthy person.

Comment: oooooo, this is going to end well.....

Answer (score 4):

You are getting some things wrong. The EMS devices usually have up to 50V output with current limited to under 10mA. Keep in mind that current in excess of 10mA "Let Go" threshold is considered extremely dangerous. By the way, commercial medical devices often use Coulombs in output ratings instead of Amperes exactly for this reason.

Now, since you are talking about attaching electrodes to neck or back I assume you want to treat pain, not stimulate muscles. This is a job for transcutaneous and subcutaneous nerve stimulators, which deliver even higher voltage (up to 350V) but in very short pulses (under 0.1ms).

Furthermore, the EMS output is usually bipolar and symmetrical, meaning equal charge is administered in two opposite directions to prevent "electrolysis" effect at contact points.

Finally, the "pulsing" is exactly what makes muscles contract. The shape of the pulse and its frequency is specifically selected to produce maximum effect with minimum nerve damage. Just applying AC from transformer will not do much, except getting electric shock if you are not careful.

Comment: Yep definitely shocks ya pretty good! I made it from a power adapter and when dry it works ok. But with gel applied holy moly! Trying to take a nap, but I’m up now! Ya sorry for the stupid question, I’m no engineer! Just a diesel mechanic! With a sore back trying to make something cheap for some quick relief! Ps if you’re on the sissy side of the rope In this life, I definitely would not recommend trying this!

Answer (score 2):

Do it on the cheap and very Safe get in ebay and order a "TENS unit" they run from about 7~16 $ US it'll do all you want and more!

Comment: "*Do it on the cheap and very Safe get in ebay and order a "TENS unit"*" Unfortunately there is no guarantee that any random TENS unit sold on Ebay will be safe.

Comment: It will almost certainly be safer than anything cooked up in a garage.